# How to avoid full memory error in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, memory, brute-force

I am trying to write a basic bruteforce type script to work on an example php page that I made. Here is the script I wrote:

```
var userElement = document.getElementById('username');
var passElement = document.getElementById('password');
//sets username, not randomized
var username = 'admin';
//expected characters
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')'];
var numOfGuesses = 0; //for fun
var numOfGuessesGenerated = 0; //for fun
var guesses1 = [];
var guesses2 = [];
var guesses3 = [];
var guesses4 = [];
var guesses5 = [];
var guesses6 = [];
var guesses7 = [];
var guesses8 = [];
var guess = "";
var memhandle = 0;

//first for loop is to get all different lengths covered, max being sixteen
var maxNumOfChars = 16;
//generates guesses one character at a time and appends them to array name guesses
for (var y = 0; y < maxNumOfChars; y++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    while (i < maxNumOfChars) {
            guess+=alphabet[i];
    }
    }
    if (memhandle == 0) {
        guesses1.push(guess);
        memhandle = 1
    } else if (memhandle == 1) {
        guesses2.push(guess);
        memhandle = 2;
    } else if (memhandle == 2) {
        guesses3.push(guess);
        memhandle = 3;
    } else if (memhandle == 3) {
        guesses4.push(guess);
        memhandle = 4;
    } else if (memhandle == 4) {
        guesses5.push(guess);
        memhandle = 5;
    } else if (memhandle == 5) {
        guesses6.push(guess);
        memhandle = 6;
    } else if (memhandle == 6) {
        guesses7.push(guess);
        memhandle = 7;
    } else if (memhandle == 7) {
        guesses8.push(guess);
        memhandle = 0;
    } 


    numOfGuessesesGenerated++;
    guess = "";
}

numOfGuessesesGenerated++;
console.log(numOfGuessesesGenerated);
console.log(guesses);

//try the guesses!
for (var x = 0; x < guesses.length; x++) {
    userElement.value = username;
    passElement.value = guesses[x];
    numOfGuesses++;
    console.log(numOfGuesses);
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); //myForm IS the name of the form
}   



document.getElementById("fid").submit();
```

The reason I included the "memhandle" variable was to try and split up all the guesses into different arrays, and that's why I have so many arrays as well. The page consistently crashes whenever I try it, is there any way i can do this in just javascript or do I need to store the usernames somewhere and then pull from there? I am injecting the javascript by just doing javascript: in the url bar and that may also be the cause of my problems.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you think splitting the items into 8 separate arrays is going to reduce the memory footprint at all?

Comment: Why store the guesses at all? Just generate a guess, test it, then toss it. Increment your counters and go on to the next one.

Comment: Read your script and think like you are the computer: place yourself in your second `for` loop (where you increment `i`). Let's say we're on the first iteration (`i === 0`). We're going through a `while` loop and repeating it until `i < 16`. First iteration of the `while` loop: we add `a` to our guess. Should we do another iteration on this `while` loop? Yes, `i` is still `0`. We add `a` to our guess. Should we do another iteration on this `while` loop? Yes, `i` is still `0`. Should we do another iteration on this `while` loop? Yes, `i` is still `0`. We add `a` to our gues.. You get the point.

Comment: @FrankerZ I thought maybe that there was a limit to the size a single array could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you're having is `while (i < maxNumOfChars) {`. This loop will never complete. You do `guess+=alphabet[i];` but you don't increment i at all (inside this loop), so it ultimately ends up with a crash.

Might I recommend looking at [iterator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to avoid an array at all?

```js
var userElement = document.getElementById('username');
var passElement = document.getElementById('password');
//sets username, not randomized
var username = 'admin';
//expected characters
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')'];
var numOfGuesses = 0; //for fun
var numOfGuessesGenerated = 0; //for fun
var guess = "";
var memhandle = 0;

//first for loop is to get all different lengths covered, max being sixteen
var maxNumOfChars = 16;
//generates guesses one character at a time and appends them to array name guesses
function *getNextGuess() {
  for (var y = 0; y < maxNumOfChars; y++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        //while (i < maxNumOfChars) {
              guess+=alphabet[i];
        //}
      }
      yield guess;
  }
}

//try the guesses!
for (var guess of getNextGuess()) {
  console.log(guess);
  numOfGuesses++;
  console.log(numOfGuesses);
  
  if (numOfGuesses > 10)
    break;
}   



//document.getElementById("fid").submit();
```